# access to ASP.NET session when using Activator.CreateInstance to execute a class method

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, session-state, activator

I have an ASP.NET site that checks for specific requests (Begin_request in global.asax).  If a certain request comes in, which in this case is executed via javascript, reflection is used to run a method in a class.

```
string[] parts = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Replace(".aspx", "").Split('/');
string cls = "" + parts[2];
string func = parts[3];

Type type = Type.GetType(cls,true);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

type.InvokeMember(func, BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, null );
```

My problem is when the method is executed `HttpContext.Current.Session` and `HttpContext.Current.User` are both null.  I suspect this has something to do with the fact the method is being executed via reflection.

Comment: You could either pass the HttpContext to your method, or, you could possibly change the way you do this - why not have a HttpHandler or Module that is invoked when a certain Url is called? That way you can handle requests in a much more natural way.

Comment: Agree with dash. HttpHandler seems the best for your need. But have you tried to send SessionID and recover the Session with this ?

Comment: Having inspected the state at Application_BeginRequest the HttpContext.Current.Session and HttpContext.Current.User are both null at this point before the method is executed via reflection.

Comment: Maybe you should look at http://forums.asp.net/t/1068656.aspx/1 , considering you need session state, using Application_AcquireRequestState seems a good idea.

Comment: @jbl - This doesn't help my situation. A HttpHandler (as suggested by dash) does not help either.  Some more information which I probably should have given you at the beginning.  I have a page with a jqgrid that makes an ajax call to get the data.  Whatever I call to get the data using the differenent methods described above HttpContext.Current.Session is always null.  I need to use this to check if session has timed out.

Comment: Maybe you should check (with firebug for example) that your jqgrid call is sending the right session cookie (ASP.NET_SessionId) to your webapp (which has to be the same webapp as your container page webapp)